# Processing data in datagridview became very slow

Tags: c#, performance, datagridview

So I have this program I made a couple of years ago that helps me process and correct data I have for my work. I run it once an year and forget about it till the next year.

I have a big data file (usually over 800k+ rows and 5 columns) that have to go through various checks for data correctness. I bind the file via an excel spreadsheet into the datagridview like this:

```
 public DataTable ReadExcel(string fileName, string fileExt)
    {
        string conn = string.Empty;
        DataTable dtexcel = new DataTable();
        if (fileExt.CompareTo(".xlsx") == 0)
        {
            conn = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=NO';"; //for above excel 2007  
        }

        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conn))
        {

            try
            {
                OleDbDataAdapter oleAdpt = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", con); //here we read data from sheet1

                oleAdpt.Fill(dtexcel); //fill excel data into dataTable  
            }
            catch { }
        }
        return dtexcel;
    }
```

Also I load the file using this:

```
private void loadExcelTable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filePath = string.Empty;
        string fileExt = string.Empty;
        OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog(); //open dialog to choose file  
        if (file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) //if there is a file choosen by the user  
        {
            filePath = file.FileName; //get the path of the file  
            fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(filePath); //get the file extension  
            textBox1.Text = filePath; //display the path to the file in the loadFile text box
            if (fileExt.CompareTo(".xls") == 0 || fileExt.CompareTo(".xlsx") == 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
                    phoneGridView1.VirtualMode = true;
                    phoneGridView1.Visible = true;
                    phoneGridView1.DataSource = ReadExcel(filePath, fileExt);
                    this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
                    MessageBox.Show("Файлът зареден успешно!", "Success!", MessageBoxButtons.OK); //custom message for successful file loading
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Моля изберете .xlsx файл.", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error); //custom messageBox to show error  
            }
        }
    }
```

After everything is loaded, I press the button and various checks on the data start happening internally (lots of ifs involved).
Last year when I did this, everything went smoothly and the checks went out for about 3h on the whole file. THIS YEAR something changed. I dont know if it is from some VS2019 update or something, but the internal checks were taking way way way more time. I let the file sit for a whole week and it didnt even check half of it.

My questions are: is there a way to get things working as before? Did some update during that year changed the way the datagridview processes data?
I didnt do any changes to the code between my last working and now. The only thing that was changed was that I changed my GPU, but I dont believe this can cause such a huge drop in performance (I upgraded, no downgraded).
Any kind of help with this issue will be much appreciated.

Sample code of internal checks for data validation:

```
private void checkEmail(string email, int i)
    {
        //counts the symbols after the @ symbol
        string afterSymbol = email.Substring(email.LastIndexOf('@') + 1);
        int lenght = afterSymbol.Length;

        if (email.Contains("@") && email.Contains(".") && lenght >= 5)
        {
            phoneGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = "01";
        }
        else
        {
            phoneGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = "02";
        }
        phoneGridView1.Update();
    }
```

Button_click function: All functions that are called here consists of various segments like the code segment above that checks the data in the datagridview

```
private void checks_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (phoneGridView1.Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            int maxRows = phoneGridView1.RowCount;
            int maxColumns = phoneGridView1.ColumnCount;
            string fieldValue;
            DataTable Codes1 = Codes(textBox2.Text);
            Codes1.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { Codes1.Columns["Column1"] };
            this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            if (Codes1.Rows.Count >0)
            {                                      
                //Check each row if it contains one of the appointed values
                for (int i = 1; i < maxRows; i++)
                {
                    fieldValue = phoneGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();


                    //Checks if the value in the row is the email
                    if (phoneGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString() == "3")
                    {
                        checkEmail(fieldValue, i);
                    }

                    //Checks if the value in the row is GSM number
                    if (phoneGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString() == "5")
                    {
                        checkGSM(fieldValue, i);
                    }

                    //Check if the telephone number is correct
                    if (phoneGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString() == "1")
                    {
                        checkTelephone(fieldValue, i, Codes1);
                    }

                    //Check if the fax number is correct
                    if (phoneGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString() == "2")
                    {
                        checkFax(fieldValue, i, Codes1);
                    }

                    //Check if the web page is correct
                    if (phoneGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString() == "6")
                    {
                        checkWeb(fieldValue, i);
                    }

                    if (phoneGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString() == string.Empty)
                    {
                        phoneGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = "19";
                    }
                }
                this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
                MessageBox.Show("Успешно проверени данни!", "Success!", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Моля въведете файл със кодовете на населените места!", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Моля въведете файл за проверка!", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I can not imagine the posted code taking hours much less a week to finish. The code simply looks like it is reading an Excel file into a `DataTable`. You state that the… _”data file (usually over 800k+ rows and 5 columns) that have to go through various checks for data correctness .”_ … where is this done and what is being “checked for correctness”?

Comment: Lets say that after I press the button, this code starts to work and it includes about 800 lines of checking various situations that the data inside the datagridview is checked and validated based on some rules. The code up on my question is the methods I use to insert the file into my program, not the consistency checks I make.

Comment: Whenever there is performance problems, doing some performance profiling is usually a good first step.

Comment: Can you recommend me a method to do so? Maybe a software for that profiling? Since I see my code is the same before, but the performance is literally bad :(

Comment: Sorry if I missed something, let me try again… I would say that if the code is dumping 800,000+ rows of data to users, then please send my sympathies to your users. I would not like having to scroll through hundreds of thousands of rows for any reason. Using the posted code, I read an Excel (.xlsx) file with six (6) columns and a little over 1 million rows. In my case my machine has plenty of ram (32GB) and a good processor (i7) and granted it took some time, but nowhere near hours. So your question and code do not match or at least I am unable to reproduce this “lag” you describe.

Comment: My initial comment was in relation to simply “reading” the data from the Excel file and my test confirms that it should not take as long as you claim. So I would think the “lag” would be coming from the 800 lines of “checking” code. I would think that “whatever” the 800 lines of code is checking… that removing the “grid” from the picture all together and instead do this “checking” of the data in the `DataTable` would be a better approach. Sorry if I am missing something.

Comment: The code literally takes the data from one of the rows, checks if it meets certain criteria and writes down a number in the last column that later on I decipher as to the type of error the data have and fix it. I dont really give any data to users, as I am working with confidential data. I also have a good processor and 32GB of memory, but the problem is once I start the process of checking the data, it fills in only 2GB of it as I see in the VS. It didnt do that last year, so Im not sure what kinds of updates there were during this time.

Comment: Well now I am confused… you state in your last comment that… _”… but the problem is once I start the process of checking the data,”_ …? … So the posted code that ONLY reads the Excel file succeeds in like 4-5 minutes (from my tests) isnt the problem? Your last comment says this problem is when “I start the process of checking the data” ? Which is it… the posted code or the checking of the data that is the problem? In other words, if the problem is “when you start the process of checking the data”… why did you post the code that only reads the data?

Comment: I would start with this approach, since we have similar ram and processor environments, then, we can set a crude benchmark as far as to how long it should take to simply “read” the data. If the posted code completes in 4-5 minutes as I can verify, then it would seem obvious that the checking code is the issue. If the posted code takes a long time to read the data like hours as you described, then it is a hardware change/update or software change/update that is the issue. I am sure you have done this but just in case… you have re-compiled the code since these changes or updates were made?

Comment: I have added 2 more segments of my program that consists of my button_click function and a sample of the internal checks that are done. I cant really add the whole thing as it is too big, but the data consistency checks are relatively the same: if statements all around that checks various cases. If that case is true, then add a number to the last column, if its false - add a different number.

The file loading into the datagridview indeed takes 3-4 minutes to load, but the problem is once the program enters the stage of checking the data.

Comment: Has the number of rows gone up? Are you using other version, maybe of Excel? Have you ever tested to see which part takes the time, like initial reading? testing? output?

Comment: For VS2019, last year I used version 16.6.0, now I updated it to 16.11.0 and things went crazy. For Excel, im still using the old 2016.
The process that takes the most time is the testing phase. It loads the data and fills in the buffer, but once its filled, it slows down significantly, because the buffer is only 2GB. I dont know how to increase it sadly.
Also, I added a function to refresh the DGV so I can see if it actually works.
And yes, the number of rows gradually go up year-to-year.

Comment: After your update, I have a few questions… 1) What is the purpose of… `DataTable Codes1 = Codes(textBox2.Text);` … ? … I can see it is a `DataTable` but “what” is its schema, what rows does it contain and “how” and “why” is it used? …

Comment: 2) We can see that inside the `for` loop through the rows in the grid, that there are numerous calls to different methods… i.e.… `checkEmail`, `checkGSM`, `checkTelephone`, `checkFax` and `checkWeb`… in this posted `for` loop code, are there additional checks being made that you did not post for brevity? Or is this the “complete” code for all the checks. If additional checks are made that were not posted, then, how many more are there?

Comment: Also, I would suggest, that since there are 800,000+ rows we need to check… that ANY “unnecessary” checks should be avoided. Example, in the `for` loop the first five (5) `if` statements ALL check the same cell two (2) value on the current row… `if (phoneGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString() == xx) {…` … ?

Comment: The problem I see here is that “IF” the first check succeeds i.e. the value in cell 2 is = 3… then the following next four (4) “if”` statements will still be “checked unnecessarily” since we already know the value is 3. That equates to 800,000+ rows X 4 unnecessary checks = 3,200,000 “unnecessary” checks. In addition because the code is structured the way it is… these 3,200,00 unnecessary steps are guaranteed to execute… This can clearly be cleaned up to avoid this. I am guessing a `switch/case` statement may be a better choice as opposed to five (5) independent `if` statements.

Comment: Lastly, since there are 800,000+ rows to check I would think you would want to make the `string` checks as fast as possible. And I am confident the fastest `string` checking is going to be done using “Regular Expressions.” Example, in the `checkEmail` code, it uses the `strings` `Substring`, `Length` and its `Contains` methods, some more than once.

Comment: Granted this will work, however these `string` methods are not very efficient and each unnecessary step taken by these methods (behind-the-scenes) can be compounded by 800,000+ rows of data. Point being, that using “Regular Expressions” for checking the `string` values “should” be a no brainer. Even if it takes extra time to implement the regular expression properly it will pay off big in the end. Sorry for the long diatribe.

Comment: Sorry but I forgot to also mention that looping through the “Grid” rows is doable… but “WHY?” It is completely unnecessary. Do the checking of the cells by looping through the `DataTable`. If you want to display this data, I would display it AFTER the checking has finished. The `DataGridView` is a UI control, and I could be mistaken, but I am pretty sure looping the `DataTable`'s rows and grabbing the cell values will be quicker than looping through the GRID rows and grabbing the cell values.